# Плавный скролл бэкрграунда для виджет игры

Tags: ios, swift, анимация

Вопрос: как сделать плавный скролл бэкграунда для игры, чтобы две картинки шли друг за другом постоянно? Вообще дело в том, что на бэкграунде около 5-6 картинок и каждый слой должен двигаться с разной скоростью (чем дальше тем медленнее) 
Теперь что я сделал. Написал метод, который принимает массив картинок и делает следующее:одни картинки выставляю на видимый экран, другие (их копии) за пределы экрана. Каждую картинку, которая видна на экране сразу, помещаю в такой(как на куске кода) аниматор, чтобы анимация повторялось постоянно, а картинки, которые за экраном, помещаю в другой аниматор (почему то в одном не работает), далее оба эти аниматора помещаю в массив, и в нужное время пробегаю по массиву и запускаю анимации.
Проблема в том, что анимации начинают вести себя совершенно не правильно, сбиваются, те что за экраном двигаются куда быстрее, чем те, что на экране(в следствии того, что картинкам нужно пройти разное расстояние за одно и то же время) и вообще выглядит это не очень красиво. 
Может быть кто знает, как все это красиво обставить, чтобы слои двигались постоянно и непрерывно, чтобы было удобно всем этим управлять.

P.S. некоторые изображения вырезаны не по размеру, поэтому приходится немного их поднимать меняя yPos.

```
func setUpBackGroundLayersWithArray(){

    var xPos: CGFloat = 0

    for  (index,image) in self.backGroundsImages.reverse().enumerate(){
        var yPos:CGFloat = -30

        switch index {
        case 1: yPos = -10
                xPos = 320
        case 2: yPos = -10
        default: yPos = -30
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        let copyimageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        copyimageView.frame = CGRectMake(320, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        copyimageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(copyimageView)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:8 - Double(index + 1), curve: .Linear, animations: {
            UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
                imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0 - copyimageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: nil)
        })
        let secondAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:10 - Double(index + 1), curve: .Linear, animations: {
            UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat], animations: {
                copyimageView.frame = CGRectMake(0-copyimageView.frame.size.width,  copyimageView.frame.origin.y,  copyimageView.frame.size.width,  copyimageView.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: nil)
        })

        self.animators.append(animator)
        self.animators.append(secondAnimator)
    }

}
```

Comment: весь код покажите

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko вставил скрин метода.

Comment: Не нужно вставлять код картинкой, ато полетят тапки в Вас. Скопируйте и отформатируйте по-нормальному.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я добился нужного эффекта. 
Если вдруг нужно будет подробно объяснить кому-то - дайте знать.
Конечный метод для бэкграунда из картинок, которые будут двигаться с разной скоростью.

```
func setUpBackGroundLayersWithArray(){

    for  (index,image) in self.backGroundsImages.reverse().enumerate(){
        var yPos:CGFloat = -30

        switch index {
        case 1: yPos = -10
        case 2: yPos = -10
        default: yPos = -30
        }

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        let copyXPos = imageView.frame.size.width + imageView.frame.origin.x
        let copyimageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        copyimageView.frame = CGRectMake(copyXPos, yPos, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        copyimageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.addSubview(copyimageView)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration:startSpeed - Double(index), curve: .Linear, animations: {

            UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: [.Repeat,.CalculationModeDiscrete], animations: {

                imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(imageView.frame, -imageView.frame.size.width, 0)
                copyimageView.frame = CGRectOffset(copyimageView.frame, -copyimageView.frame.size.width, 0)

                }, completion:nil)
        })

        self.animators.append(animator)
    }

}
```